# Why does my CSS rotation complete instantly?

Tags: html, css

I've been researching like mad and have used this property before, but it is just not working for me. It just displays as already rotated.

I suspect it's an issue with my browser, but just wanted to check that my code was ok.

Thanks!

```css
.logosmall {
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(420deg) scale(1.8);
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" class="logosmall" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "*It just displays as already rotated*" That is because the initial value of that class is already rotated. If you want to ***see*** the rotation happen, the value either needs to change (*after the initial value is read and displayed*), or you should use an [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations).

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? btw install some syntax checker for your editor as you have errors in css syntax -- scale will not work like it was in your initial version

Comment: Be aware that tables aren't a proper way to do layout in 2022. Maybe there's more to this than meets the eye, but....

Answer (score 3):

It's because transition kicks in only for changed initial value. And your initial value is already rotated image. Use `@keyframes` for that.

```css
.logosmall {
  width: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: .3s ease-in-out 0s 1 rotateImage forwards;
}

@keyframes rotateImage {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0) scale(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(420deg) scale(1.8);
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:15%"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" class="logosmall"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Probably worth mentioning the alternative without keyframes. Having a separate class that is added later which just [uses transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) as @EssXTee mentioned in the comments

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out with some help from Justinas. I wanted it to rotate on hover so just added appropriate code:

```
.logosmall:hover{transform: rotate(420deg); scale(1.8); transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;}
```

and have the width etc in a different css that is not on hover.

Works perfectly now!